# How to select childnode (unknown) in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I added some svg-graphic with mouse-events like mouseover and mouseout.
On mouseover I'd like to add a hover-class to the svg and on mouseout, I'd like to delete it.

My svg Looks like this:

```
<g><line id="1..n" class="redline graphic" x1..../></g>
```

In my Event I get the g-tag with this Code:

```
d3.select(this).node()
```

so far, fine. But how can I get the first Child (in this case the line), so I could Change it's classes, similar to this:

```
d3.select(this).node().firstChild.classed('hover', true);
```

I think I've missed a select but I couldn't find how to solve it **:-(**

Comment: Ok, for now I solved it this way: `d3.select(this).select("line").classed("graphicmouseover", true);` but how can I do it, if I don't know, that it is a line?

Comment: `d3.select(this.firstElementChild).classed("graphicmouseover", true)` will do the trick. Since you have `this` pointing to the parent element you can directly access its first child element and create a selection from that.

Comment: **Perfect**, I will try this. Thank you!